# Django ORM raw query how manage quotes

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, orm

In my Django project i have to implement a complex RAW query for extract data, for doing this i use the raw django function.
The original query is:

```
SELECT FT."Riferimento1", FT."Riferimento2", "CodProdotto", "QuantitaFatturata", "PrezzoUnit", "DataFattura", "NumeroFattura", "CodCli"
FROM public.idocuments_as_fatturetestata FT
LEFT JOIN public.idocuments_as_fatturerighe FR ON FT."Riferimento1" = FR."Riferimento1" AND FT."Riferimento2" = FR."Riferimento2"
WHERE FT."CodCli" = '12192';
```

if i run directly in pgadmin SQL all was done

In django i implement in this fashion:

```
>>> from idocuments.models import as_fatturetestata as asf
>>> a = asf.objects.raw("SELECT FT."Riferimento1",FT."Riferimento2","CodProdotto","QuantitaFatturata","PrezzoUnit","DataFattura","NumeroFattura","CodCli" FROM public.idocuments_as_fatturetestata FT LEFT JOIN public.idocuments_as_fatturerighe FR ON FT."Riferimento1" = FR."Riferimento1" AND FT."Riferimento2" = FR."Riferimento2" WHERE FT."CodCli" = '12192'")
```

but i get:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

maybe the problem is how to manage quotes but i don't understand how transport the sql query into raw directive.

Someone can help me please?

so many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try using single quotes and escaping the single quotes within the string with `\`:

```
a = asf.objects.raw('"SELECT FT."Riferimento1",FT."Riferimento2","CodProdotto","QuantitaFatturata","PrezzoUnit","DataFattura","NumeroFattura","CodCli" FROM public.idocuments_as_fatturetestata FT LEFT JOIN public.idocuments_as_fatturerighe FR ON FT."Riferimento1" = FR."Riferimento1" AND FT."Riferimento2" = FR."Riferimento2" WHERE FT."CodCli" = \'12192\'"')
```